# Including shell script in ConfigMap using Helm ends in YAML errors

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to mount a shell script template into a container.

I have the following `configmap.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "myservice-chart.fullname" . }}--scripts-configmap
  labels:
    app: {{ template "myservice-chart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "myservice-chart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  setup: |
    {{ include "setup" . | indent 4 }}
```

And this is my `setup.tpl`:

```
{{- define "setup" }}
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world!"
{{- end }}
```

When I do a Helm dry-run, Helm generates this (valid) YAML:

```
...
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: listening-donkey-myservice-chart-quorum-scripts-configmap
  labels:
    app: myservice-chart
    chart: myservice-chart-0.1.0
    release: listening-donkey
    heritage: Tiller
data:
  setup: |

    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Hello world!"
...
```

When I run it without `--dry-run`, it generates this error:

> configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: did not
>   find expected key

Answer (score 6):

According to [helm chart template guide](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/):

> The curly brace syntax of template declarations can be modified with
>   special characters to tell the template engine to chomp whitespace.
>   {{- (with the dash and space added) indicates that whitespace should
>   be chomped left, while -}} means whitespace to the right should be
>   consumed. Be careful! Newlines are whitespace!

So, in order to prevent an useless empty line below `setup: |` the  `configmap.yaml` should be the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "myservice-chart.fullname" . }}--scripts-configmap
  labels:
    app: {{ template "myservice-chart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "myservice-chart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  setup: |
    {{- include "setup" . | indent 4 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Helm creates a useless empty line below `setup: |`, hence incorrect indentation.

This is how I fixed it:

```
...
data:
  setup: |
    # Useless line to prevent "did not find expected key"
    {{ include "setup" . | indent 4 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing so should be enough, add the '-' sign in the beginning and in the end

```
data:
setup: |
# Useless line to prevent "did not find expected key"
{{- include "setup" . | indent 4 -}}
```